# c++ assembley inline codes error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, .net-assembly

I have written some assembly in-line  codes like the codes below:

```
void write_sb(BYTE bIdx, DWORD dwVal){
_asm {
    mov dx, 0x0cf8
    mov eax, 0x80003800
    mov al, bIdx
    out dx, eax
    mov dx, 0x0cfc
    mov eax, dwVal
    out dx, eax
} 
}
```

running the function make  0xC0000096: Privileged exception. not only this function but all assembly inline codes throw exceptions and I don't know what to do with it! some searches told me about running my codes in kernel mode. I did not find how can I run assembly in-line codes in kernel mode or how to fix in another way. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link helped me out!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e10813e-9813-4e84-89f9-845eaa941c27/c-assembley-inline-codes-error?forum=vcgeneral

we need to write kMDF driver.